# Cannot set a very simple object attribute to an object with a many:many relationship

Tags: django

I'm learning django and cannot seem to just literally add a message to an automation. I have a POST method and I should be able to add a message to an automation (both Message and Automation classes have a many to many relationship).

This is how the automation is logged just before trying to add the message:

```
before {'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7fbd47a27370>, 'id': 9, 'name': 'test bobbie automation', 'description': 'a test bobbie automation', 'account_id': 34, 'date_created': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 27, 8, 55, 52, 723100, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

It has no messages, but the class denotes a many:many relationship between messages and automations, so I see no reason why it cannot be added.

What am I doing wrong here? I’ve tried all of these but to no avail:

```
    # automation.messages.set(msg) 
    # automation.messages.append(msg)
    # automation.messages.add(msg)  # does not work
    # automation['messages'] = msg
    automation.messages.set(msg)
```

Where the latest attempt fails with `TypeError: 'Message' object is not iterable.`

View:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin', 'customer'], own_account_only=True)
def automation_add_message(request, pk, automation_id):
    account = Account.objects.get(id=pk)
    automation = Automation.objects.get(id=automation_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        msgId = request.POST.get('message_id')
        msg = Message.objects.get(id=msgId)
        print('before', automation.__dict__)
        # automation.messages.set(msg)  # error here @todo
        # automation.messages.append(msg)
        # automation.messages.add(msg)  # does not work
        # automation['messages'] = msg
        # also fails with TypeError: 'Message' object is not iterable
        automation.messages.set(msg)
        print('after', automation.__dict__)
        automation.save()
        print('saved')
        redirect_url = '/accounts/' + pk + '/automations'
        return redirect(redirect_url)
```

Models:

```
class Automation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Message(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    text = models.TextField()
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    automations = models.ManyToManyField('automations.Automation', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Probably an easy fix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `.set(…)` method, you should pass an iterable of items, so for example a list:

```
automation.messages.set([msg])
```

this will however not *add* `msg` to the messages of the `automation` object, it will remove all items, and add `msg`.

If you want to add `msg` to the `.messages` of `automation`, you work with:

```
automation.messages.add(msg)
```

there is furthermore no need to save the `automation` object, since a `ManyToManyField` works with a "hidden" model, so you can remove the `automation.save()` method call.

Comment: strangely whenever I try both add or set like how you specified, it doesn't seem to show whenever I print the automation after. Do you think it might have to do with the fact that initially the automation has no messages at all? It print this: `after {'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7f83c28dc7c0>, 'id': 9, 'name': 'test bobbie automation', 'description': 'a test bobbie automation', 'account_id': 34, 'date_created': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 27, 8, 55, 52, 723100, tzinfo=<UTC>)}`

Comment: @user8758206: the item *has* messages, this is *not* in the model dictionary, you can see these with `print(automation.messages.all())`. A `.__dict__` will only show the `_state`, and the fields defined for *that* model, not that of the junction model constructed by the `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: also printing the result prints `account_id` instead of just `account`, whereas the class uses `account` - is this normal?

Comment: @user8758206: as for `.add(...)` or `.set(...)` you should pick one of the two. `.add(msg)` will add a message, so the existing message will still be there, whereas `.set([msg])` will remove all messages and then add `msg`.

Comment: @user8758206: it is normal to print `account_id`, since if you make a `ForeignKey`, Django will internally use a `foreignkeyname_id` to save the column it refers to in the referenced model. Django's meta logic will fetch the related object if you use `.account` with an extra database query.

Comment: In general it is simply *not* a good idea to work with `.__dict__`. If you want to serialize an object, you can work with the [*serializers* of the Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

Comment: that's handy to know. Got it working after using `.add` and `automation.messages.all() `, thank you